# Lubuntu 12.10: Icon Display Problems

Tags: 12.10, graphics, icons, lubuntu

First off, I would like to let you know that I am new to Linux. I finally decided to give it a try and my first project was installing **Lubuntu** on an old PC and using it for a media server for my PS3.

So, one thing that I noticed right away is that **my icons for applications, files, folders, etc...are not visible**. If I move my mouse over the name of the application or file (It only works if I move the mouse up from the bottom of the name) then the icon will appear, but if I move my mouse back over any other place on the file the icon will disappear again. Also, if I open a folder sometimes an icon or two will be displayed but the rest won't, and like I said before if I move my mouse over the top of the application or file the icon will disappear.

Is there any way to fix this? Is this normal? Or could it be a problem with my hardware? I never had this issue when I was running the last OS (Windows XP). Any help would be greatly appreciated. Remember, I am new to Linux so a thorough explanation would be helpful.

Also, if there are any tips, tricks, references, or recommendations any of you have to help me jump in and become more familiar with using Linux that would be great! I'm very interested in taking advantage of the power Linux has. Currently I am studying computer programming so maybe one day I will be able to develop my own Linux distribution.

Comment: This is true, I experience the same problem with Ubuntu 12.04.2 and Lubuntu 13.04

Answer (score 2):

Try this;
go to

> preferences > Customize Look and Feel > Font

then change Sub-pixel geometry to None

For extra Drivers go to:

> preferences > Software Sources > Additional Drivers

Comment: changing the Sub-pixel geometry worked for me. Thanks! Any chance you could explain why this works?